# Can't install Ubuntu on Asus Rampage V

Tags: boot

I can't install Ubuntu or start Ubuntu live on my PC. I have a (ca. 2014) [Asus Rampage V](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/RAMPAGE_V_EXTREME/) motherboard and an Intel [i7-5960x](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/82930/intel-core-i7-5960x-processor-extreme-edition-20m-cache-up-to-3-50-ghz.html) CPU. When I want to start Ubuntu from a LiveUSB on this six year old design, I got this message :

[image: Screen pic of boot failure]

I tried 18.04 and 20.04 but error is the same.

Yes. It works on Windows 10. I tested cpu with prime95, Realbench and 3dMark and every test was fine. I updated bios on motherboard to Version 4101 - 2019/07/17.

I tried Xubuntu installation, but the system froze during installation. I tried CentOS to with CentOS-8.1.1911-x86_64-boot but result was the same, system froze.

I also tried with Load optimal defaults in Bios, but it didn't help.

This is very similar problem that I have (if not the same) :

[Can't install Ubuntu on Asus Rampage Extreme IV](https://askubuntu.com/questions/430377/cant-install-ubuntu-on-asus-rampage-extreme-iv)

I manage somhow to enter in Live 20.04 and get dmesg:

[image]

When I tried to install system from Ubuntu Minimal (mini.iso), installtion stuck on 78% Selecting the kernel to install....
[image]

Comment: does windows work?

Comment: Please download the Xubuntu ISO and try it, following these instructions: https://askubuntu.com/a/1242546/197910 then please click [edit] & add the results to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.

Comment: You may need to update microcode from Intel.  Take a look at this [document](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/sa00115-microcode-update-guidance.pdf).

Comment: Microcode is updated. But problem persist. Definitely compatibility issue.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to boot with kernel option "acpi=off noapic"

[image]

and only one core works...

Answer (score 0):

I just installed 20.10 beta. And it works :) dmesg errors are the same , but it works.
[image]
[image]

All cores are active without modification :)

It looks like that developers read this post! Thanks!!